# Use of linkcolor option in hyperref

Tags: hyperref

This question is posted as a requested follow-on from [options for appearance of links in hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/options-for-appearance-of-links-in-hyperref/477072?noredirect=1#comment1204433_477072) , to clear up some odd behaviour in hyperref.

In the snippet below, the two \usepackage commands both work, but `linkcolor=.` throws an error when combined with `colorlinks=true` *(error text shown at end of post)*.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[linkcolor=.]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

See Figure~\ref{fig}

\begin{figure}
        \caption{This is an empty figure \label{fig}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If I use the line

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=.]{hyperref}
```

(note the dot), I get error text:

> LaTeX Error: Undefined color

and the error comes immediately after the closing brace of `\ref{}`

The effect I wanted to achieve was to remove boxes around links and leave all links text color except actual URLs, so when I used this command I also had `urlcolor=blue` in the options, but that was not needed to reproduce the error. But the following line did work, in that all links but URLs were invisible:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=]{hyperref}
```

Using MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6959 (1.40.20) (MiKTeX 2.9.6960) on Windows 10

Comment: Add `\usepackage{xcolor}`.

Comment: Of course you get an error with `linkcolor=.` as this is setting the colour to `.`, which is a non-existent colour. SImialrly, with `linkcolor=` you are remving all colour so the lins are invisible. Doesn't `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
` give what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your advice to add xcolor. Perhaps hyperref should be loading it? I did not want to assume text was black. linkcolor=. is supposed to match the current text colour. See the discussion linked in the question for context. linkcolor=. works under some circumstances. The dot on its own is not necessarily an error.

Answer (score 5):

`linkcolor=.` causes hyperref to issue `\color{.}`

which produces

```
LaTeX Error: Undefined color `.'
```

as there is no colour of that name using the standard `color` package as loaded by `hyperref`.

You are possibly thinking of the `xcolor` package syntax wher `.` means the current color

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=.]{hyperref}
```

works, although specifying coloured links this way seems slightly strange choice rather than just specifying the link border to have width 0.

Comment: Strange to you. Seemed reasonable to me, with my lack of experience. I didn't want a border, so saying 'colour it instead' and then making the colour like the text seemed reasonable to me.

Comment: @DrDarren there is some cost to adding a colour, the resulting pdf will have code to push a colour on to the stack and restore it, just using the current colour, conversely a pdf link always has a border attribute so setting its width to 0 (`pdfborder= 0 0 0`) is a far more direct and lightweight way of specifyng this

Comment: Thank you for that advice. All I can say is that I did what I did as a naïve user and to me it seemed logical. It is great to have so much expertise out there, and people willing to give their expertise. I wanted one kind of link to be blue and the rest invisible. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, as noted above, adding

\usepackage{xcolor}

fixes the problem with using the dot in the hyperref options. There are other ways of getting the result I wanted that also do not throw errors; thanks to other posters.

Perhaps hyperref should load xcolor instead of color?