# Footnote shows color tag before number

Tags: footnotes, xfootnote

Whenever I create a footnote, it will appear as reference**red**^footnote number.
I haven't changed the declaration of the color of the footnote anywhere or made any other modifications on them.

Comment: Probably that's because you have `hyperref` turned on colors. See answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/options-for-appearance-of-links-in-hyperref).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: clearly this is an error in code that you have not shown. Make a small self contained document that shows the problem and add it to your question.