# LaTeX: make float appear in "list of" without displaying any label

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

My question is a follow up of [Cryptocode: Cref should link to a game, and write its name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623163/cryptocode-cref-should-link-to-a-game-and-write-its-name) : so far, in a `memoir` document I display some "figures" (typically in a new float environment) representing a cryptographic game:

[image]

As the name of the game is already written at the top of the box, I don't want to put any caption. However, I still want to be able to provide the list of all games, using for instance the `\listof{floatGame}{List of Games}` command provided by the `float` package.

How could I make sure that the name of the game is printed in the table of content, without adding a visible caption?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage [
n,
advantage,
operators,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
asymptotics,
keys
] {cryptocode}
\createprocedureblock{gameProc}{center,boxed}{}{}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{floatGame}{htb!}{Game}
\floatname{floatGame}{Game}

\makeatletter
% Usage: \begin{mygame}[label][short title]{title} content \end{mygame}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{game}{soomb}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\begin{floatGame}[htbp]}{\begin{floatGame}[H]}%
      \caption{#4}%
      \begin{pcimage}%
        {\normalfont\gameProc[linenumbering]{#4}{\IfValueTF{#2}{%
              %% Add an anchor if a label is present
              \raisebox{1em}{\hypertarget{#2}{}}%
              %% Create a macro "mygametitle@nameoflabel" to store the title
              \IfValueTF{#3}{% If a short title is provided
                \expandafter\gdef\csname mygametitle@#2 \endcsname{#3}%%
                \write\@auxout{\gdef\string\mygametitle@#2{#3}}%
              }{%
                \expandafter\gdef\csname mygametitle@#2 \endcsname{#4}%%
                \write\@auxout{\gdef\string\mygametitle@#2{#4}}%
              }%
            }{} #5 }}%
      \end{pcimage}
    \end{floatGame}%
  }{}
  
% Usage: \refGame{label}
\NewDocumentCommand{\refGame}{m}{%
  \hyperlink{#1}{\csname mygametitle@#1\endcsname}% Do not put a white space after #1!
}

\makeatother

\definecolor{secondaryColor}{RGB}{206,149,0} %% darker orange, looks like gold. <3
\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  allcolors=secondaryColor % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50754/
]{hyperref}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\listof{floatGame}{List of Games}

\section{Content}

I provide a new environment \verb|game|, where you can specify an optional star (to insert it into a floating figure), an optional label (\textbf{WARNING: do not use any number in the label}) if you want to refer to it later, an optional short title (used when citing the game), the real title, and finally the content.
\begin{game}*[myGreatGame][$\indcpa$]{$\indcpa_\enc^\adv(\secpar)$}
  b \sample \bin  \\
  (\pk,\sk) \sample \kgen (\secparam)  \\
  (\state,m_0,m_1) \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c)   \\
  c \sample \enc(\pk,m_b)  \\
  b' \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c, \state) \\
  \pcreturn b = b'
\end{game}

You can then refer to the game using \verb|refGame|, like \refGame{myGreatGame}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: My idea would be not to use the figure environment for the table of games but to follow the idea given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77992/a-list-of-all-the-labelled-sentences?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein, thanks, it works great!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Harald Lichtenstein, this question [works](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77992/a-list-of-all-the-labelled-sentences?noredirect=1&lq=1) (I heard that some tocloft packages was not compatible with `memoir`, but the above answer works also in `memoir`): the command `\@starttoc{game}` displays the toc (make sure to use `\makeatletter...\makeatother` around it), and `\addcontentsline{game}{section}{#4}` adds something in the toc.

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage [
n,
advantage,
operators,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
asymptotics,
keys
] {cryptocode}
\createprocedureblock{gameProc}{center,boxed}{}{}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{floatGame}{htb!}{Game}
\floatname{floatGame}{Game}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand\listofgames{O{List of Games}}{\chapter{List of Games}\@starttoc{game}}

% Usage: \begin{mygame}[label][short title]{title} content \end{mygame}
% Première Etoile: dans un float
% Deuxième étoile: n'ajoute pas dans la table of contents.
\NewDocumentEnvironment{game}{soomsb}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\begin{floatGame}[htbp]}{}%
      \begin{pcimage}%
        \phantomsection\IfBooleanTF{#5}{}{\addcontentsline{game}{section}{#4}} %
        {\normalfont\gameProc[linenumbering]{#4}{\IfValueTF{#2}{%
              %% Add an anchor if a label is present
              \raisebox{1em}{\hypertarget{#2}{}}%
              %% Create a macro "mygametitle@nameoflabel" to store the title
              \IfValueTF{#3}{% If a short title is provided
                \expandafter\gdef\csname mygametitle@#2 \endcsname{#3}%%
                \write\@auxout{\gdef\string\mygametitle@#2{#3}}%
              }{%
                \expandafter\gdef\csname mygametitle@#2 \endcsname{#4}%%
                \write\@auxout{\gdef\string\mygametitle@#2{#4}}%
              }%
            }{} #6 }}%
      \end{pcimage}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\end{floatGame}}{}%
  }{}

  
% Usage: \refGame{label}
\NewDocumentCommand{\refGame}{m}{%
  \hyperlink{#1}{\csname mygametitle@#1\endcsname}% Do not put a white space after #1!
}

\makeatother

\definecolor{secondaryColor}{RGB}{206,149,0} %% darker orange, looks like gold. <3
\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  allcolors=secondaryColor % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50754/
]{hyperref}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\listofgames

\chapter{Content}

I provide a new environment \verb|game|, where you can specify an optional star (to insert it into a floating figure), an optional label (\textbf{WARNING: do not use any number in the label}) if you want to refer to it later, an optional short title (used when citing the game), the real title, and finally the content.
\begin{game}[myGreatGame][$\indcpa$]{$\indcpa_\enc^\adv(\secpar)$}
  b \sample \bin  \\
  (\pk,\sk) \sample \kgen (\secparam)  \\
  (\state,m_0,m_1) \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c)   \\
  c \sample \enc(\pk,m_b)  \\
  b' \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c, \state) \\
  \pcreturn b = b'
\end{game}

\begin{game}*[$blabla$]{$bleble$}*
  I should not be included .
\end{game}

You can then refer to the game using \verb|refGame|, like \refGame{myGreatGame}.

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

In the memoir class, you can replace the line `\NewDocumentDommand\listofgames...` with:

```
\newlistof{listofgames}{game}{List of figures}
```

it will avoid starting the chapter on a new double page. However, I'm curious to know how it manages to start a chapter without creating a new page... If anyone knows, I'm interested!

**EDIT**

Actually, I checked and I found a way to start a chapter on a non-right page using \openany... and one can also redefine \def\clearforchapter{...} to start a chapter on without creating a new page.

Comment: Functionality similar to `tocloft` is build directly into `memoir` (mostly they are name the same way, but not always)

Comment: @daleif ok, good to know, thanks! Btw, I added "\chapter*{List of games}" to add the title of the table of contents, but it is pushed on a page starting on the right page. On the other side, `\listoffigures` starts a chapter that does not even need to start a new page (I need to manually add it). Any idea how `\listoffigures` manages to use the style of `chapter` without creating a new page?

Comment: I managed to find a solution (see my edit), but I'm curious to understand how it works internally: I can't find any way to create myself a chapter that won't create a new page.

Comment: `\tableofcontents` and friends uses the chapter interface to typeset their titles, but not `\chapter*` or equivalent. They do not force a page break since if you only have a few tables and figures, you might want to have the list of tables and list of figures on the same page. Technically they define `\Xheadstart`, `\afterXtitle`, `\printXnonum` and `\printXtitle` which are initialised to their `X=chapter` equivalents. And they always use page style `chapter`.

Comment: @daleif cool, thanks a lot! Actually, I checked and I found a way to start a chapter on a non-right page using `\openany`... and one can also redefine `\def\clearforchapter{...}` to start a chapter on without creating a new page :D

Comment: That is not a good idea. What is your reasoning you you to need a chapter that does not start a new page?

Comment: @daleif similarly, to create a small section in the frontmatter, maybe a "notation" page, or something similar. And for curiosity ^^'