# How to add hyperlink in Latex generated pdf (without a surrounding bluebox)

Tags: hyperref, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks)

I want to generate a pdf from latex with hyperlinking text - i.e. when some part of text in the pdf is clicked, the associated URL should be opened.

I know that this could be done by `\href{webpage address}{(My Text)}` but this generates a blue box around the text. I don't want to see the blue box around, just when the user moves the mouse cursor over it, I want to show the hand cursor - and then the user can click to visit the link.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks) question.

Comment: BTW, welcome to tex.sx!

Comment: I've removed the introduction from your question (it's preferred not to have introductions and greetings in the questions). I have also formatted your code as inline code, which you can do by enclosing it in backticks.

Answer (score 17):

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Ha, that's excellent! I had to update my `hyperref` for this to work (seems it was only added in the latest version). You should post this on the question lockstep linked to in his comment.

Comment: Congratulations -- this is the first time I upvoted an answer to a question I had already voted to close. (And `hidelinks` will make it into my personal preamble.)

Comment: @meep.meeo : Thank you, meep - concise and perfect solution.

Answer (score 6):

Another option, to customize it, is:

```
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
```

This way you can customize the color and the borders.

Comment: Extending Weslei's beautiful answer, I am using this: `\usepackage[colorlinks=true ,urlcolor=blue,urlbordercolor={0 1 1}]{hyperref}`