# Chapter ref with LaTeX

Tags: cross-referencing

In LaTeX, we can say something like:

```
"See equation \ref{eq} on page \pageref{eq}..."
```

Is there any way to do:

```
"See equation \ref{eq} in chapter \chapterref{eq}..."
```

Comment: @Zsub: Doing both often leads to the question be migrated _and_ reposted here on tex.sx, so we get _exactly_ exact duplicates. So please don't comment!

Comment: @brian: What should `\chapterref` return? The number or the name of the chapter?

Comment: @brian: It would be great if you would elaborate your question a bit! @answerers: If the question is interesting so that you liked to answer, consider to upvote the question as meaningful. The number of 6 answers doesn't match the 0 votes for the question. ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I would like \chapterref to return the chapter number. It would be very helpful to know how to return the chapter name as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 54):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) offers `\autoref` which will turn `\autoref{chap:foo}` into "chapter *X*"

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Foo}
    \label{chap:foo}
    
    This is the beginning of \autoref{chap:foo}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: chapter foo]

To edit how hyperref references appear, see answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823/215)

[`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) is another package that offers this sort of functionality.

[The LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing) has details on various cross-referencing options.

Comment: This does not seem to address the original question, which asks about extracting the chapter reference from the item (eg, equation) within the chapter.

Comment: @Lev I don't think it's obvious _what_ the question is asking for. Certainly not to the extent that this answer ought to be downvoted for being off topic.

Comment: @Seamus Well you won't for sure, I hope, subdue what is true to what majority think is true. The question asks explicitely for a *way to quote a chapter number through a reference label declared in the chapter*. Your answer provides a *way to automatically get chapter number through the chapter label*. You do agree I hope that the two statements are completely different. Thus, you don't answer the question at all. But I do agree that you can not care as you get upvotes.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this with the `zref` package. Here is an example use:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{chapter}{\thechapter}
\zref@newprop{chaptertype}{\@chapapp}% as suggested by Danie Els
\zref@addprop{main}{chapter,chaptertype}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{ch1}
  ch1
\chapter{ch2}
  ch2
  \begin{equation}\zlabel{x1}
     x=1
  \end{equation}
\chapter{ch3}
  See equation~\zref{x1} in chapter~\zref[chapter]{x1}.
  Or, Danie's suggestion (in case you move equations between
  chapters and appendices): 
  See equation~\zref{x1} in \zref[chaptertype]{x1}~\zref[chapter]{x1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The hardcoded `chapter~....` is a problem if the equation is inside an appendix. Maybe a `\zref@newprop{chaptertype}{\@chapapp}` for the book classes. Note that AMSbook uses `\chaptername`

Comment: @Danie Well, that wasn't part of the original question, but I edited my answer as you suggested to automatically show the chapter/appendix type.

Comment: Please stop the sarcasm.  I had tried to help by suggesting points that will make the overall solution better, even if the OP didn’t asked for it.

Comment: @Danie, Sorry, I didn't intend any sarcasm, but I can see how you saw it that way, so I have edited again to make it clear (hopefully) that I was giving proper credit for your suggestion, and to separate the part that is necessary for the original question versus the improved version that deals with an issue that maybe the OP didn't even consider.

Comment: It works fine just that I needed to replace `\zref@addprop{main}{chapter,chaptertype}` by `\zref@addprop{main}{chapter} \zref@addprop{main}{chaptertype}`.

Answer (score 4):

As meep.meep already posted the `nameref` can be used to reference to the name of the chapter. However, to get it right you need to label and reference the chapter manually and not use the label of the equation.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap:intro}

\begin{equation}
  E = m\cdot c^2 \label{eq:emcsq}
\end{equation}

\chapter{Other}\label{chap:other}

% By name: "See equation 1.1 in chapter Introduction."
See equation~\ref{eq:emcsq} in chapter~\nameref{chap:intro}.


% By number: "See equation 1.1 in chapter 1."
See equation~\ref{eq:emcsq} in chapter~\ref{chap:intro}.

% Or both: "See equation 1.1 in chapter 1 ``Introduction''."
See equation~\ref{eq:emcsq} in chapter~\ref{chap:intro} ``\nameref{chap:intro}''.


\end{document}
```

The `~` before `\ref` is to prevent a line break just at this position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I think this doesn't really my answer. I would like to use \chapterref{label_of_some_equation} and not ...label_of_some_chapter. This is because if I reorganize things, I won't be able to refer to the right chapter anymore. Thanks!

Comment: @brian: The reason why `\pageref` works is that `\label` writes the page number to the `.aux` file. But the name or number of the chapter is not written. However, this could be added.

Comment: Do you know how to add this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @brian: I do not know any package which does this already. The `\label` command must be changed to also write the chapter information into the `.aux` file which then can be used by `\chapterref`.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this using the package `nameref` (which you don't have to load, if you use `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\begin{document}

\section{Testsection}

\begin{equation}
x=y 
\label{eq:test}
\end{equation}

See equation  \ref{eq:test}  in  section \nameref{eq:test}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: I just noted, that if you also have a `\subsection{text}` then `\nameref`would refer to this rather than the section. If I find the solution to this, I'll supplement it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would love it if you could find a way to fix it.

Comment: @brian: I had a look at the documentation of `nameref` and I suspect that this problem would be solvable. However, my knowlege of this LaTeX level is basic at best. So, I would recommend asking a new question like `How to modify nameref to always refer to the current chapter?` or something like that.  Sorry, that I can't help you further.

Comment: `\nameref` worked for me, but, for anyone who might wonder, it gave the chapter's name. Not its number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use labels to sections and subsections, then refer to them like you'd refer to any other float, see below:

```
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Background}
\label{sec:bg}

tesagahgshlgasghagö as seen in \ref{sec:bg} ......
```

Comment: This does not seem to address the original question, which asks about extracting the chapter reference from the item (eg, equation) within the chapter

Answer (score 1):

I can see two somewhat manual ways to do it:
1) Introducing an additional counter, that passes the number of the chapter containing the equation:

```
% in preamble
\newcounter{einst-chap}

% around the equation
E=mc^2 \label{einst} \setcounter{einst-chap}{\value{chapter}}

% and to reference
See equation \ref{einst} in chapter \arabic{einst-chap}...
```

However, you have to take care of the format (eg. you'd have to type `\Roman{einst-chap}` if you had chapter I, chapter II etc.), which makes this solution not fully automatic.

2) Storing the adequate value of `\thechapter` (which includes the format as well as possible superdivisions, eg. chapter A#3), using `\edef`:

```
% just after the equation
\edef\einstChap{\thechapter}

% and to reference
See equation \ref{einst} in chapter \einstChap...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a package called `cleveref`. It automatically recognise what you are referring to and adds the appropriate name and numbering style.

in the previous example (by Daniel Els) you use it like this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}\label{chp:Chp1}
\cref{eq:Einst} in \cref{chp:Chp1} and \cref{eq:Feyn} in 
\cref{chp:App1} it is ...
\begin{equation}
   E=mc^2 \label{eq:Einst}
\end{equation}

\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}\label{chp:App1}
\begin{equation}
  e^{i\pi}-1 = 0 \label{eq:Feyn}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This requires two labels: One for the chapter and the one for the equation -- this might get tedious

Answer (score 0):

The `refstyle` package has this functionality. It will correctly reference an Appendix also if your label is such. You can also link it to `varioref`. Please read the documentaion.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}\label{chp:Chp1}
\Eqref{eq:Einst} in \chapref{chp:Chp1} and \eqref{eq:Feyn} in \chapref{chp:App1} it is ...
\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{eq:Einst}
\end{equation}

\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}\label{chp:App1}
\begin{equation}
  e^{i\pi}-1 = 0 \label{eq:Feyn}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to address the original question, which asks about extracting the chapter reference from the item (eg, equation) within the chapter

Comment: This answer does actually address the question in a different way. It is was I was looking for anyway, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Put these commands in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\chap}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{Chapter \ref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Chap}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{Chapter \ref{#1}}, \nameref{#1}}
\newcommand{\chaps}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{Chapters \ref{#1} \& \ref{#2}}}
```

then the text looks something like

```
In \chap{C4} we proved that... and in \chaps{C2}{C1} we claimed that...
```

etc...

Comment: @user1999 This seems an odd approach to take. `hyperref` defines its own  `\autoref` command that effectively does this. (See my answer)

Comment: This does not seem to address the original question, which asks about extracting the chapter reference from the item (eg, equation) within the chapter