# Decide whether a label occurs in the current chapter

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals, zref

I want to decide if some label occurs in the same chapter as the current one. I use the `zref` package as suggested in [Chapter ref with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13622/chapter-ref-with-latex) to find out in which chapter a label occurs, and compare this to the current one. I tried to do this with both the counter's *display* and *value*.

Here is what I do:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[user]{zref}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{chapter}{\thechapter}
\zref@newprop{chaptervalue}{\the\value{chapter}}
\zref@addprops{main}{chapter,chaptervalue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\zlabel{chapone}

Compare \thechapter{} with \zref[chapter]{chapone}. Equal:
\ifstr{\thechapter}{\zref[chapter]{chapone}}{Yes.}{No.}
Compare \thechapter{} with \zref[chapter]{chaptwo}. Equal:
\ifstr{\thechapter}{\zref[chapter]{chaptwo}}{Yes.}{No.}

Compare \the\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{chapone}. Equal:
\ifstr{\thechapter}{\zref[chapter]{chapone}}{Yes.}{No.}
Compare \the\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{chaptwo}. Equal:
\ifstr{\thechapter}{\zref[chapter]{chaptwo}}{Yes.}{No.}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\zlabel{chaptwo}

\end{document}
```

In any case, the result is "No.", even if the values are equal.
I was using `\ifstr` from the KOMA-Skript package to compare the strings (as I am using this documentclass anyway), but this also happens when one uses other string comparison functions (I have tried `\ifthenelse{\equal{<str1>}{<str2>}}{<true>}{<false>}` from the `ifthen` package and `\IfStrEq` from the `xstring` package).

Does anyone understand why this happens? Or can you imagine another way to compare these values?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the "expandable" version of `\zref`, which is `\zref@extract`; the optional argument to `\zref` makes impossible to use it for this kind of comparisons.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[user]{zref}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{chaptervalue}{\the\value{chapter}}
\zref@addprops{main}{chaptervalue}

\newcommand\comparechapter[1]{%
  \ifstr{\number\value{chapter}}{\zref@extract{#1}{chaptervalue}}{Yes.}{No.}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\zlabel{chapone}

Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{chapone}. Equal:
\comparechapter{chapone}

Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{chaptwo}. Equal:
\comparechapter{chaptwo}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\zlabel{chaptwo}

\end{document}
```

I've used only `chaptervalue`, so this is independent from the representation of the chapter number.

[image]