# Renew only the reference on section part for \ref

Tags: cross-referencing

I had to declare `\thesection` without its fitting chapter. But the reference should always include the `\thechapter`. Does anyone has a workaround? I guess,

```
\let\origref\ref
\renewcommand\ref[1]{
    %ref to chapter.%
    \ref{#1}
}
```

## Some more information

class: `scrbook`

`hyperref` is used

## Tried things

I tried to use

```
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}
\chapref
```

but this refs on the section.

Comment: Possible dup of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13703/18414

Comment: Hm.. Probably I have to redefine ref and Label to use that. I need to apply This referencing to a huge  document and the solution should be applied easyl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References can be prefixed by `\p@<counter>` that can be defined to contain `\thechapter`:

```
\documentclass{report}

% Section numbers without chapter number
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

% Section references with chapter number
\makeatletter
\def\p@section{\thechapter.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\label{sec:second}
See section \ref{sec:second}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thats the solution I was looking for. Thank you!
I discovered, that we can easily enlarge this to subsection and subsubsection.