# How to format a link properly?

Tags: hyperref, links

I tried using:

```
\href{mailto:user@some.org}{user@some.org}
```

and

```
\href{mailto:user@some.org}{\nolinkurl{user@some.org}}
```

but it just gives a purple box around the link, and I want it to look like a [normal link](http://google.com). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Try loading `hyperref` like this: `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - Thanks, that worked!

Comment: Maybe this can be combined with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try loading `hyperref` like this:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```