# \href without decoration (no underline)

Tags: hyperref, text-decorations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks)

I would not show the hyperlink underline decoration when I use `\href` macro from `hyperref` package.

I would obtain an effect similar to [html-css style="text-decoration: none"](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp), if it is possibile.

Comment: `hyperref` doesn't underline links by default, but puts boxes around it, which can be switched off: [Remove ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 0}` to disable the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 0}

\begin{document}
\href{http://www.google.com}{The Google}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `hyperref` also has the option `hidelinks`, which switches the boxes off completely, see [Remove ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823) Probably best to close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: @Jake: Agreed. Voted to close as dupe.

Comment: I've seen that xdvi show different appereance and that colorlinks option filtered my output.
Currently I understand better that options' bunch.