# Changing PDF links style

Tags: pdf, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks)

When I generate PDF, a red border surround all links (internal and external).

- Which package draws this borders around links automatically ?
- How I can change this behavior, so link text become blue, instead of putting in box?

Comment: -1: Please do your research more thoroughly before posting a question here. It is trivial to go through the packages you're using and single out the one responsible for the borders, `hyperref`. Once you've figured that out, you find all the options you need in the [`hyperref` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: @doncherry Red boxes are generated automatically without using a special package. And that was the question, I never used \hyperref.

Comment: @Reza: I Disagree, this generates no boxes: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}\label{Foo}\ref{Foo}
\end{document}`. Hence, your document class (≠ `article`) might be loading `hyperref`. As for external links, which macro do you use? It must be provided by some package as well.

Comment: @doncherry You are right. I found source of that issue, thanks

Comment: It takes a lot less time to google this question than to go through the packages, so asking this question for others to read makes the world better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides all of the functionality you seek. Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue!50!red,
  urlcolor=green!70!black
}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\label{firstsec} Visit \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.SX}.
\section{Second section}See Section~\ref{firstsec}.
\end{document}
```

`colorlinks=true` provides coloured links (rather than bordered links), after which you can specify a variety of colours, depending on the link type. From the [`hyperref` documentation](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-80003.4):

- `linkcolor`: default is `red`; Colour for normal internal links.
- `anchorcolor`: default is `black`; Colour for anchor text.
- `citecolor`: default is `green`; Colour for bibliographical citations in text.
- `filecolor`: default is `cyan`; Colour for URLs which open local files.
- `menucolor`: default is `red`; Colour for Acrobat menu items.
- `runcolor`: default is `filecolor`; Colour for run links (launch annotations).
- `urlcolor`: default is `magenta`; Colour for linked URLs.
- `allcolors`: set all colour options (without border and field options).