# Format Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks)

I downloaded a Latex model to build my finishing degree course, but the summary came in a strange format, like in image, each section became a link with a red tectangle around it.

[image: Summary]

I took a look at the code and didn't find out how to take it off this red rectangles.
These are the packages in the file:

```
\documentclass[svgnames,12pt,oneside, openright,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{chngpage,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{conf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[portuguese, english, brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
```

Can anyone  help me?

Comment: This to do the links set by hyperref, try `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` instead of `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: You may also try removing, or commenting out (%) the line `\usepackage{hyperref}` if you do not need hyperlinks. The red rectangles disappear on print-outs.

Comment: Before posting such a question, please figure out which package is responsible by commenting them out one by one and compiling afterwards, until the problem disappears. Then you've found the package responsible.

Comment: Also, `hyperref` should usually be loaded as the last package. For exceptions to this rule, see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863)