# Get rid of box around URL with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks)

Let's say we have document with url:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
\end{document}
```

How to get rid of box around url (and ensure it's black) ?

(pdflatex)

Comment: I agreee, it'd duplicate. Please close question. (I think it might be worth to leave or even re-edit with more key-words, because I had problem to find mentioned question with key-words and tags I've been using)

Comment: I added the [tag:links] and (somewhat abusive) [tag:boxes] tags to the original question.

Comment: Good idea. I hope it will helps others like me.