# Acronym hyperlink without special color

Tags: hyperref, acronyms

I use the `acronym` package for managing acronyms. 
I would like to show the acronym hyperlink without special colors or borders, just as plain text.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Alternatively use [hyperref - Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks?noredirect=1&lq=1) to remove the red boxes globally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Package `acronym` uses `\AC@hyperlink` for its links. This can be redefined to locally set option `hidelinks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}[2011/02/05]

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\AC@hyperlink}[2]{%
    \begingroup
      \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
      \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ac{foo} and \ac{foo}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{foo}[FB]{FooBar}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

If you want to get rid of the link entirely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}[2011/02/05]

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\AC@hyperlink}[2]{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ac{foo} and \ac{foo}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{foo}[FB]{FooBar}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```