# in classicthesis, change acronym hyperlink colour (to black) but leave crosslinks blue

Tags: hyperref, acronyms, classicthesis

I am trying to change the acronym link colours in classicthesis to black but leave other links their default colours.
I have tried the solution listed here: [Acronym hyperlink without special color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73063/acronym-hyperlink-without-special-color)

However when I try that solution (see below), the document no longer compiles

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\AC@hyperlink}[2]{%
    \begingroup
      \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
      \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}

I get the error:

Undefined control sequence. (\hypersetup ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the main file, just before /begin{document} works

```
% adjust colour of acronyms
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\AC@hyperlink}[2]{%
    \begingroup
      \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
      \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother
```