# How to change hyperlinks color {Lyx}

Tags: hyperref, color, lyx

I am using Lyx and i would like to change the color of hyperlinks on my bibliography.
The default color is pink (at least on report layout , which i am using)
Is it possible to change it, to blue ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the manual of hyperlink (p14), you should write something like this in your preamble:

```
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}
```

Comment: One can add the `urlcolor=blue` instruction, as well as others controlling hyper-links, in **Document** > **Settings** > **PDF Properties** under the **Additional options** field. For example, a _custom_ set of instructions may be the following: `linkcolor=magenta, urlcolor=marineblue, citecolor=blue, pdfstartview={FitH}, hyperfootnotes=false, unicode=true`

Comment: `Undefined control sequence \hypersetup` while using `\usepackage{url}`. Why?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris For some reason, this doesn't work for me. The color is still red. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @roi.holtzman What is your setup? OS and LyX version? [`hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en) installed? **Use Hyperref Support** enabled? Code only in the **Additional Options** field? Any conflicting entries in the **LaTeX Preamble**?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris LyX Version 2.2.2, Osx El Capitan 10.11.6. I don't know if `hyperref` is installed. I think it is installed because the links are working and are painted red. In the preamble I have `\usepackage{url}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}` and the code I use in the 'additional options' field is `urlcolor=blue`.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris great suggestion to add hypersetup under **Document > Settings > PDF Properties > Additional options**. Some of my documents returned a Latex error `"undefined color 'brown'"`. To fix the error I added `\usepackage{xcolor}` to the Latex Preample.