# Configure link color in url package

Tags: urls

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82531/44531) discusses configuring link color in Lyx, however the accepted answer (or the question) doesn't address or solve my problem.

If I use this setting, as suggested:

```
% Enable links
\usepackage{url}
% But I hate pink!
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}  % Undefined control sequence \hypersetup
```

So how does `url` package handle this? [The documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/url/url.pdf) (googled, may be outdated) doesn't even mention word color...

Comment: use `hyperref` instead of the `url` package. `\hypersetup` is part of `hyperref`.

Comment: The `\hypersetup` is from the package `hyperref`. Just replace `url` by `hyperref` and put the whole thing at the end of your preamble. If you encounter other problems with my approach, let us know, which.

Comment: Turns out I had been including `hyperref` too, so  moved the configuration there. Should I remove the include for `url`?

Comment: That would be fine, yes :) `hyperref` loads `url` IIRC. At the very least, it provides the same functionality.

Comment: It's still a good idea to load the `url` package separately (and, if you do so, *before* you load `hyperref`) *if* you need to use options such as `hyphens` (useful if you want to allow line breaks at hyphen characters).

Comment: I'd love to know why pink is the default, it seems "the best" of all choices.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this package:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Also, you can check out a detailed example here https://www.overleaf.com/project/5fe24ef7f829ed77be10f39f