# How do I change hyperlinks' color only?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, hyperlink

I link a page using `\href{url}{anchor text}` in beamer. I followed this instruction [How to change hyperlinks color {Lyx}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/how-to-change-hyperlinks-color-lyx) to change the url color.

```
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}
```

It doesn't work. The following one works.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks,
     urlcolor    = blue
}
```

However it changes url color not just hyperlinks, but `section` in navigation bars, as shown below.

[image]

**How do I change hyperlinks' color only?**

---

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks,
     urlcolor    = blue
}
\usepackage{color}
\urlstyle{same}

%%% The title pape
\title{Title}

\author{Author}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]%[shrink=20]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection, currentsubsection, sectionstyle=show/show, subsectionstyle=show/show/show]
\end{frame}


\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{URL color}
URL color: \href{http://example.com/}{Text 1}
\end{frame}

\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{URL color}
URL color: \href{http://example.com/}{Text 1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Option `colorlinks` of package `hyperref` sets colors for all link types.
Class `beamer` does not use this option, but uses option `pdfborder` to remove the link annotation rectangles.

The problem can be solved by using the special color `.` of package `xcolor` that refers to the current color:

```
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  allcolors=.,
  urlcolor=blue,
}
```

First, the colors to all link types are set to the current color. Then,
the color for URLs is set to blue.

Package `xcolor` is automatically loaded by class `beamer`.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  :(  My case is slightly different. I also included the option 'linkcolor=blue' of package 'hyperref'. Then, all links of the header and the footline become blue. How can avoid this? [EDIT: This is answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481025/prevent-hyperref-from-changing-the-color-of-section-and-subsection-hyperlinks ]

Comment: This worked! Thanks!