# Text color with hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, color

I wanted to use the hyperref package and I looked for help and I found a lot of solutions. However, I used this option that look great, as I could control the colors.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = red, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = blue %Colour of citations, could be ``red''
}
```

After usuing the `\usepackage{hyperref}` I saw that the full text color changed from black to grey. I printed it to see if the problem is only in pdf format, but without  `\usepackage{hyperref}` become darker than with  `\usepackage{hyperref}` .
How can I have the dark text and using `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

here are the images (sorry for the text in portuguese):
with `\usepackage{hyperref}`
[image]

ahd without `\usepackage{hyperref}`
[image]

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, 
  urlcolor     = blue,
  linkcolor    = blue, 
  citecolor   = blue 
}

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}


\begin{document}


\section{Monetary and Fiscal Policy rules}\label{sec:policyrules}

\subsection{Introduction}\label{subsec:intro}

I must confess to not seeing a difference in blackness/grayness of the text across the two samples.
Mico you are right. these images do not show clearly the difference. But if you pay more attention you can see that the second one is darker than first. And in the printed version the difference is bigger 
A part of the problem is that it's hard to compare the two samples on screen: on contains four lines but the other only three. Could you repost the second example, showing four lines as well? 
Mico here you are. I edited the second image. i think now the difference is clearly. 

hyperref does not change the main text color. Thus the effect is probably quite unrelated to this package. One reason can be the use of color. This can be tested with package color and textcolor without hyperref. Or there are transparencies (images, ...) involved. It is known, that AR uses a different rendering method then. 

You should provide a fully compilable minimal working example that only contains the lines necessary to reproduce the problem. Then it is easier for others to help you.

Can be a font problem.

Yeah, there isn't much we can do until we have a full MWE that we can print ourselves and compare.


\citet{Taylor1993} 

 \citep{Zheng.etal2012, Froemmel.etal2011, Hayat.Mishra2010, Moura.Carvalho2010, Consolo.Favero2009}. 

 \citet{Svensson2000, Ball1999}

 \citet{Taylor2002} 

\begin{align}
\label{eq:regrapm}
    i_{t}&= \mathcal{M}(\Omega_{t})+\epsilon^{\mathcal{M}}_{t} \\
\label{eq:regradesp}
    G_{t}&= \mathcal{G}(\Omega_{t})+\epsilon^{\mathcal{G}}_{t} \\
\label{eq:regrarev}
    R_{t}&= \mathcal{R}(\Omega_{t})+\epsilon^{\mathcal{R}}_{t}
\end{align}

\citet{Clarida.etal2000}, da seguinte forma:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:jurosequilibrio}
    i^{\ast}=\mathfrak{m}_{0}+\mathfrak{m}_{1}\left(E\left[\pi_{t,k}|\Lambda_{t}\right]-\pi^{\ast}\right)+
                    \mathfrak{m}_{2}E\left[y_{t,q}|\Lambda_{t}\right]+\mathfrak{m}_{3}E\left[X_{t}|\Lambda_{t}                  \right]
\end{equation}


\subsection{Conclusion} \label{subsec:conclusion}



\bibliographystyle{mybibstylept}
\bibliography{thesisbiblio}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I must confess to *not* seeing a difference in blackness/grayness of the text across the two samples.

Comment: @Mico you are right. these images do not show clearly the difference. But if you pay more attention you can see that the second one is darker than first. And in the printed version the difference is bigger

Comment: A part of the problem is that it's hard to compare the two samples on screen: on contains four lines but the other only three. Could you repost the second example, showing four lines as well?

Comment: @Mico here you are. I edited the second image. i think now the difference is clearly.

Comment: `hyperref` does not change the main text color. Thus the effect is probably quite unrelated to this package. One reason can be the use of color. This can be tested with package `color` and `\textcolor` without `hyperref`. Or there are transparencies (images, ...) involved. It is known, that AR uses a different rendering method then.

Comment: You should provide a fully compilable [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that only contains the lines necessary to reproduce the problem. Then it is easier for others to help you.

Comment: Can be a *font* problem.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't much we can do until we have a full MWE that we can print ourselves and compare.

Comment: @Canageek I edited the question and included the MWE.

Comment: @Gilson That is far from a MWE. Look at all the packages in there. You want to use as few packages as possible to reproduce the problem, ideally just the one. Cut them out a few at a time and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @Canageek I didn't understand your comment. All the packages are needed for my full file. Could you test if its working in your program?

Comment: @Gilson We are trying to diagnose a problem with one package. We want to eliminate the possibility another package is causing the problem. See: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe

Comment: @Canageek I think I did it.

Comment: This must be a viewer problem.  Taking your non-minimal WE, which is incidentally missing bibliography information and custom style file, I got uneven output viewing Skim which became even after zooming and then zooming out again.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your help. I found the solution. I should include this package: `\usepackage{xcolor}` ... Now it's work perfectly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about missing the xcolor package.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer... just include `\usepackage{xcolor}`

Comment: That would mean, the problem is unrelated to `hyperref`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I think it is. In my point of views, if we are using `hyperref` with `\hypersetup`, we have to include `xcolor` package. Am I wrong?

Comment: The differences are between "no color", package `color` and `xcolor`, thus no relation to `hyperref`.