# Removing red boxes around references

Tags: hyperref, formatting

I have seen some solutions on here to problems regarding removing red boxes from hyperlinks, but I have an issue with red boxes around references. Whenever I use the commands `\eqref{}` or `\footnote{}` the number in the PDF has a big red box around it. I have linked the issue to my `classicthesis` package. I like the formatting of this package, but I don't want to have red boxes around my references. What can I do?
My document preamble is:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}-\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
```

Comment: Isn't http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks what you need?

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{hyperref}` before `\documentclass` will remove them quite for sure, but it will remove all functionality of `hyperref`. For other solutions, use answers in what @egreg linked.

Comment: @egreg, I tried that but then it complained that the package conflicted with the command \begin{document}

Comment: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.14 \title
           {Alternate Methods of Calculus with Absolute Value Functions}

Comment: `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` should do. An example of your document preamble should be needed, add it to your question.

Comment: Using something like `\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, linkcolor =blue, anchorcolor = red, citecolor = DarkGreen, urlcolor = MediumBlue}` will remove the boxes and set the colour of the links to whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

I avoid the option clash for `hyperref` by loading:

```
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
```

The last package in my preamble is:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=Maroon, urlcolor=Maroon]{hyperref}
```

Obviously, you should use your own preferred colours.

I struggled with this for quite a while when I was designing the template for a scholarly journal but after some digging around, settled on this. I don't have time just now to re-trace the steps I took in finding this out but I will do so if nothing comparable works for you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should definitely come back and elaborate on this answer

Comment: @Christian Oh, and thanks for the warm welcome!

Comment: Just had a quick check. The (Boolean) option `colorlinks` is set to false by default. If set to true, it colours the links rather than putting them in a bounding box. The manual gives an indication of this (but it is not wholly clear). The manual will be at `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/latex/hyperref/manual.pdf`; refer to section 3.5

Answer (score 0):

the answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923066/how-to-get-rid-of-the-red-box-around-hyperlink-in-pdf

it is

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```