# hyperrefs in textcolor

Tags: hyperref, color

I have used `hyperref` (with `xcolor`) and

```
\hypersetup{
  linkcolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  urlcolor=black,
  citecolor=black
}
```

for quite some time now. However, in a coloured text this looks somewhat silly. Is there a (simple) way to turn of link colours completely? I also do not want these (mostly red) boxes, the links should just look as normal text.

Comment: Have you tried `hidelinks`?

Comment: [Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823)

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks, that helped a lot. Sadly, In Tex Live 2009 (Ubuntu 12.04) the option hidelinks is not present, but there is a helpful answer nevertheless.

Comment: TeX Live is sooo old, i recommend to make an update before starting your next project.

Comment: Is `hidelinks` really not available with `hyperref` from 2009?

Comment: Options `hidelinks`, `allcolors`, `allbordercolors` were added in version 2011-02-05 v.6.82a.

Comment: Oh, that's a pity.

Comment: In short, try to update your system to TeXLive 2014. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use the current color `.` defined by the `xcolor` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=.,filecolor=.,urlcolor=.,citecolor=.}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}\label{test}
{\color{blue}See \ref{test}},
{\color{orange}see \ref{test}}, 
see \ref{test} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, although it should be noted, that for newer versions than Tex Live 2009 there are better options (see the comments above).

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on keeping texlive 2009, install a new hyperref, e.g. from here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

You can install into your ~/texmf, and if it doesn't work, simply remove it again. Watch out, if your ~/texmf includes a file `ls-R`, you have to update it, say `texhash ~/texmf`.

Comment: It is easiest if the OP installs using the `.tds.zip` file.