# Is it possible to declare document to be math-free to stop "Missing $ inserted"?

Tags: math-mode

I know that it it possible to either escape every single underscore (`\_`), or apply `\usepackage{underscore}`.

Escaping is tedious, underscore package breaks `\textbf{a_b}` and `\includegraphics{filename_with_underscore}`.

Is there a better solution for math-free texts including multiple underscores (in my case - in URLs)?

Comment: If you use [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), you can go with `\url{http://www.example.com}`, the [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package offers a similar command.

Comment: `_` should work without problens in includegraphics

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If the document is math free, then ``\catcode`_=12`` in the preamble will do, provided you also have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: it is better to mark URL with `\url{http://.....}` (url or hyperref) as then line breaking is better handled but if you want `_` to be a normal character use ``\catcode`\_=12`` make sure you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as OT1 fonts do not have the `_` character.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - ``\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`` with ``\catcode`_=12`` did what I wanted. Maybe hyperref with ``url{http://...}`` is the proper way, but it has obnoxious defaults (bright teal eyesore around every url - why? why?).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - are you interested into promoting your comment to an answer? I would accept it.

Comment: @moewe ``url`` is not adding bright teal eyesore around every url like ``hyperref``, but it is also not working out of the box - urls are refusing to respect margins, despite possibility to fit it by adding line break before url).

Comment: `hyperref` adds hyperlinks to URLs (these are by default marked with boxes), you can disable this behaviour or modify it (see, [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823/35864) for example), line breaking in URLs is a tricky issue (see for example [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/35864))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is better to mark URL with `\url{http://.....}` (url or hyperref) as then line breaking is better handled. Note that `url` package will just allow linebreaking in URLs and doesn't add any annotation. `hyperref` uses the same code for linebreaking but also makes the link an active link. By default this adds coloured decoration but the package has several options to control or disable that.

But if you want _ to be a normal character use

```
\catcode`\_=12
```

make sure you have

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

as OT1 fonts do not have the `_` character.

Answer (score 15):

You can have your underscores print as such outside math mode and doing their usual business in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\catcode`_=12
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_\lowercase{\endgroup\let~\sb}

\begin{document}

Under_score and $a_{1}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the problem of colored URLs, just load `hyperref` with the relevant option. With `\urlstyle` you can also change the default font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}

\catcode`_=12
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_\lowercase{\endgroup\let~\sb}

\begin{document}

Under_score and $a_{1}$, see at
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}


\bigskip

\urlstyle{rm}

This URL uses the normal font
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that Knuth has prepared the `\mathcode` of `_` as math-active (which starts to be active if the catcode of `_` is changed from 8 to 12), but this activity has had another purpose: to draw the underline character. Maybe the reason was that Knuth has had missing underline character in his fonts. This is very curious historical reason why we have not set the `_` as math-active to do `\sb` and ``\catcode`_=12`` by default in all formats. Unfortunately.

Comment: @wipet The fact that the glyph `_` is not in `cmr10` has certainly to do with this. Anyway, I stand with the choice of making `_` category code 8, as it helps in catching syntax errors.