# how to let the long web-link automatically break line?

Tags: line-breaking, urls, links

I use the \tt in the latex, however, it can not break line automatically. Then, I add \\ in the link, e.g. `\tt{http://tex.stackexchange.com/ \\\\ questions/ask}`. Then, in the generated pdf file, it seems I can not click the link and jump to that website.

It seems `\url` can break line automatically, however, it use package `hyperref`. This package will add the citation a colored box. This is what I should avoid.

So, do you have any suggestion to use \tt?

Comment: Welcome! `\tt` is deprecated. In general, you should use `\ttfamily` or `\textt{}` instead.

Comment: So basically, you want to use `hyperref` but hide the boxes around the links? If so, don't use the "hackish" method you're using, Use `hyperref` and load the `hidelinks` option. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823/4778

Answer (score 4):

If you use `\url` from the `url` package it just enables line breaking without any links.