# Latex click reference to jump to reference

Tags: bibliographies

I have a .bib file with reference. But when i click on [1] it does not take me to the reference page ? I also want the blue box around it. I dunno what settings to type. And my reference not citing in order. Like I have this

```
@CONFERENCE{Dalal,
  author = {N. Dalal and B. Triggs},
  title = {Histograms of oriented gradients for human detection},
  booktitle = {Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
  year = {2005}
}

@CONFERENCE{1997Merlino,
  author = {P.Dollar, R.Appel, S.Belongie and P.Perona},
  title = {Fast feature pyramids for object detection},
  booktitle = {TPAMI},
  year = {2014}
}
```

but when i cite Dalal 1st it prints [2] instead of [1]. And also i edit bib but latex not updating the citation. My bib not updating because after i edit all my citation lost. Help thanks

Comment: Add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your preamble -- and read the [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) manual!

Comment: ok but now all my content page got red boxes

Comment: For question marks, it's a common question related to compilation look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/92620), as for the red box, to disable it you need to load the package with an option: `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12408/92620), you may want to set url color to blue `urlcolor=blue`.

Comment: For the order how citations are named it depends on the style you are using, which you didnt specify here. `\bibliographystyle{comes here}` unless you are using the one by default.

Comment: Thanks all ! The suggestions you all posted have helped me fix all my problems !

Comment: @SAM Can you post an asnwer?

Comment: Mine doesn't work. I created  a MWE: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gjjsfvmwyjmw. Can some one please help me?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Firstable you must include `\usepackage{hyperref}` in your preamble, about question marks, it's a common question which is related to compilation, you have to use a compilation chain like mentionned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/92620).

About the red box mentionned in the comment, to hide/disable it, you need to load the  `hyperref` package with the option `hidelinks` this way `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` ([also it's a common question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12408/92620)).
You may want to set url color to blue using the option `urlcolor=blue`.