# Clicking on a citation doesn't jump to its location in references

Tags: citing, overleaf

Here is a MWE: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gjjsfvmwyjmw

If you click on the citation `[1]` on top of the page 4 in the MWE I created, you will see that it doesn't jump to the references. Can any one tell me why clicking on the citation `[1]` doesn't bring me to the references?

I looked over [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317941/latex-click-reference-to-jump-to-reference), but couldn't fix it.

[image]

Comment: Load `hyperref `after loading the other packages.

Comment: @Ivan That fixed it!. Thanks. I can accept your comment as answer if you post.