# Why over my table of contents there is a red frame

Tags: xetex

I have the following sample of tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,25pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

% Uncomment it and uncomment any \lipsum notation as well.
% Afterwards build and see how beautifull result is displayed
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=numeric-comp, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{./material.bib}

\usepackage[pdfauthor={"John Doe"},
    pdftitle={"Hello I am a seifuku"},
    pdfsubject={"iot"},
    pdfkeywords={"seifuku"}
]{hyperref}    
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmainfont[Kerning=On,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Univercity Of MOE OTAKUS}
\fancyhead[R]{Legion on Otakus \& Weabos}


\title{Motteke Seifuku}
\date{Univercity of Moe Otakus - 2018}
\author{Dimitrios Desyllas (Nekomimi1233)}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Introduction}
        \lipsum[1-20]

    \chapter{Motteke Seifuku}
        \section{Seifukus Rocks!!!}
        \subsection{Generic information}
          This is a nice list \cite{US7791415B2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Seifuku are awesome
            \item Watashiwaravuseifuku
            \item whatecer I want
        \end{enumerate}

    \lipsum[5-9]


        \subsection{Frequencies of seing seifuku}
    \lipsum[5-9]

        \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \lipsum[1-20]

    \chapter{Implementation of Lorem Ispum}
        \section{Introduction}
        \lipsum[1-8]
        \section{Materials Used}
        \lipsum[5-10]
        \section{Projects Implemented}
        \lipsum[7-13]
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And I have the following bibliographic entries (`material.bib`):

```
@patent{US7791415B2,
    author="Craig A. {Hornbuckle}",
    title="{Fractional-N synthesized chirp generator.}",
    year="{2007}",
    location="{US}",
    url="\url{https://patents.google.com/patent/US7791415B2/en}",
    assignee="{Semtech Corp}"
}

@misc{CHIRPMODULATION,
    url="\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_spread_spectrum}",
    title="{Wikipedia: Chirp spread spectrum}"
}
```

But for some reason I get colored frames over:
* url in biblioography
* citations
* Table of contents

As the images shows:

[image: Red Frame over table of contents]
[image: Green Frame over Citations]
[image: Blue Frame over urls]

DO you know why that happens and how I can make it disappear?

Comment: Check the answers here please: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks.. This is `hyperref` package effect

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on the package `hyperef`:

```
\usepackage[pdfauthor={"John Doe"},
    pdftitle={"Hello I am a seifuku"},
    pdfsubject={"iot"},
    pdfkeywords={"seifuku"}
]{hyperref}
```

In order to solve it put the option `hidelinks` making it:

```
\usepackage[pdfauthor={"Dimitrios Desyllas, Ioannis anagnostou"},
    pdftitle={"Setting up a LoRa IoT communication using LoRaWAN"},
    pdfsubject={"iot"},
    pdfkeywords={"privacy by design, privacy, howto, technologies, legal requirements"},
    hidelinks
]{hyperref}
```