# Package keyval Error: hidelinks undefined

Tags: hyperref, packages, package-options

I wish to remove color boxes around references and links in my document. According to [answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks) I tried `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` in preamble, but received the following error during the compilation:

```
! Package keyval Error: hidelinks undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1830 \ProcessOptionsWithKV{Hyp}

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.1830 \ProcessOptionsWithKV{Hyp}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on thesis.log.
```

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [ChangeLog](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/ChangeLog.pdf) of package `hyperref`:

> 2011-02-05  6.82a  Heiko Oberdiek
>
> - 6.82a
> - Options `hidelinks`, `allcolors` and `allbordercolors` added.

Update `hyperref`.