# Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references for Equations and Footnotes but keep them for figures, table and citation

Tags: hyperref, color, boxes, links

I know that hyperref can make cross-references and hyperlinks clickable and I know how to get rid of all the border(the little green boxes around the clickable area) from this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks), but I would like to know how to keep some of those green boxes(I would prefers to keep the border for figures and tables, but not for math equations and simple footnotes.)

Again, this is my current setting:

```
\usepackage[citecolor=red,filecolor=black,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

But I would like to get rid of the border **only for** equations and footnotes.

Comment: Have you tried setting the option `colorlinks`?

Comment: @Mico The OP wants `colorlinks` for *some* cross references, but not all.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - I don't think that the OP had mentioned `colorlinks` anywhere. FWIW, I think that having colored rectangles around some types of hyperlinks but not around others verges on the bizarre.