# Option clash with package for hyperref usepackage when converting document to aomart

Tags: compilation-error

I am trying to convert a `.tex` document from `\documentclass{article}` to `\documentclass[final]{aomart}`.

When I try to compile the document, I get the following error message:

```
line 17 Option clash for package hyperref. \usepackage
```

The script is:

```
1  \documentclass[final]{aomart}
2  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
3  \usepackage[title]{appendix}
4  \usepackage{parskip}
5  \usepackage{amsmath}
6  \usepackage[english]{babel}
7  \usepackage{pgfplots}
8  \usepgflibrary{arrows}
9  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
10 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
11 \usepackage{tikz}
12 \usepackage{amssymb}
13  \usepackage{cancel}
14  \usepackage{float}
15  \usepackage[section]{placeins}
16  \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
17  \usepackage{enumerate}
18  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
19  ...
```

I tried removing `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` or `\usepackage{enumerate}`, but I get other messages.

How should I fix this issue?

**Update**

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[final]{aomart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
    xxx
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Please also remove the line numbers, if we are going to work on a solution for your problem, we would have to painstakingly remove them before we could compile a document.

Comment: the package `hyperref` with rare exception should be loaded last. please provide complete but small document which we can test and see, what is the problem.

Comment: Sorry. I have added a MWE.

Comment: why you need option `hidelinks`? without it your example work fine. also links are not visible, however ithey are active.

Comment: @Zarko: It's because I followed this advice: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12408/165510.

Comment: `aomart.cls` as you have noticed already loads `hyperref` with options. Have you tried specifying the option via `\hypersetup{ hidelinks }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aomart` class already loads `hyperref` with options, thus you get an option class if you ask for other options.

If really needed, then use

```
\hypersetup{
  hidelinks
}
```

in your preamble instead. You can do this with most `hyperref` options (if not all).

BTW: `enumitem` is probably more recommended to use for lists than the old `enumerate` package

Comment: I removed `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` and modified the 1st line to `\documentclass[hidelinks,final]{aomart}`. The issue is gone.