# How to remove color from table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to remove the red color around the table of contents. How do I do that? Below there is a picture of my table of contents and my preamble:

[image]

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf, it}]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, textfont=it}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{10}{12}}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textgreek}
```

Comment: The outline comes from the hyperref package. If you want no hyperrefs to have boxes around them change `\usepackage{hyperref}` to `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823/172164 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an option on the package hyperref. Use this command:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

Instead of:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```