# How to have the box around the references and acronyms?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, cross-referencing

I saw a thesis which has red rectangles around acronyms links to the acronyms and figures and tables numbers, and green rectangles around the references.

[image]

I have `\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}` in the latex file, what changes should be added to have these boxes in the text?

Comment: Without the `colorlinks=true` option you will get colored boxes instead of colored text.

Comment: As @leandriss said, oddly this the default option, I guess that for historic reasons,  but do you really want colored boxes?  Take in mind that many readers may not like that format, but a (non-very distracting) colored text (including black).  This is not an opinion. One of most upvoted question is how [Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks).

Comment: @Fran thanks for your suggestion. I think your point really makes sense.