# Footnote without reference

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes

I am currently writing my bachelor thesis with LaTeX and I want a footnote without a reference. I used a blank footnote with:

```
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup}
```

It makes me a footnote  at the end of a page without a number as I wish, but then a red box appears at the end of the page in the pdf. With `\footnotetext`, I can create a footnote without the reference, but it needs a number. Is there an option to get rid off the reference AND the number?

Currently its like this: (I need the `hyperref-package` for url and references and the other footnotes)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, bibtotocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
I want a footnote without reference and without a number.\blfootnote{This creates a footnote without number but with reference.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May one ask _why_ you would want this? It seems to go against the spirit of a footnote.

Comment: @gmvh I am not the OP, but my organization actually uses this construct in certain situations on our technical reports.  For example, our Appendix titles appear on a page by themselves.  If there is a footnote associated with the appendix title, it is to appear as an unnumbered, unlinked footnote.

Comment: @gmvh I use this feature to make a link from from the first page of a preprint to the publisher's copy of a paper.

Answer (score 2):

Here, `\freefootnote` will create the desired footnote without a number and without a link.  As shown in the MWE, it does not interfere with the use of linked, numbered footnotes elsewhere in the document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, bibtotocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote
\newcommand\freefootnote[1]{%
  \let\thefootnote\relax%
  \footnotetext{#1}%
  \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
}
\begin{document}
I want a footnote without reference and without a number.%
\freefootnote{This creates a footnote without number 
  and no longer with reference.}

Regular footnote.\footnote{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `hidelinks` option to hyperref in your preamble should do the trick (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks)). Put into a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, bibtotocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
hidelinks % hide link outlines
]{hyperref}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
I want a footnote without reference and without a number.\blfootnote{This creates a footnote without number but with reference.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This approach seems to remove links from *all* footnotes, not just the `\blfootnote`s.