# How to remove the hyperlink box created by thanks?

Tags: pdftex, footnotes, titles, author, hyperlink

I am new to the thanks command. I was trying to add the funding for two authors and I used something like

```
\newcommand*\samethanks[1][\value{footnote}]{\footnotemark[#1]}

\author{First Author\thanks{Supported by some funding}}
\author{Second Author\samethanks}
```

and it seems there is a very ugly hyperlink box and after some search I couldn't find a way to get rid of it. Also I am not sure if the way I used to add thanks to both authors is correct.
Thank you in advance for any suggestion and advice.

[image]

Comment: Use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` instead of the first `\thanks`.  See page 48 of hyperref manual.

Comment: What document class are you using.  The definition of \thanks varies.

Comment: @JohnKormylo just a4paper

Comment: a5paper is a document class option.  article is a document class.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I see, yeah I am using article

Comment: You must be loading some package to allow you to create more than one author.  I tried to reproduce a MWE and got only the second \author.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `hyperref` package? You should add the `hidelinks` option. That is,

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

This will remove the borders and colors of all hyperlinks. It is not clear if you want to do this only for the acknowledgements.

Note: You ask about adding the acknowledgements separated. An alternative editorial option is to add only one footnote to the title or to the last author and state "Author1 thanks..." "Author2 thanks..." etc

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out a way myself. May not be a very clean way, but at least it works.

The idea is to just add two asterisks manually to the two authors, and then add a footnote without any label and link through the method described in this post: [Footnote without reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562763/footnote-without-reference)