# How can remove the red rectangle around text?

Tags: hyperref

[image]

I try using Google Chrome it is not works

Comment: Could you please show the code you use? This is probably linked to `hyperref`.

Comment: This is the default of `hyperref` and only visible in the pdf viewer (not printed). It can be changed by setting the `linkcolor=<any color>` option of `hyperref`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823/5764)