# How does one typeset a URL?

Tags: pdftex, urls

I'd like to insert a URL into this document. Is there a "correct" way of doing that? If so, is there a way to turn it into a link inside the final pdf generated with pdfTeX or XeTeX?

Comment: Seems like a [duplicate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-to-make-clickable-links-and-cross-references-in-pdfs-produced-by-latex)

Comment: @TH: Close enough to a distinct question that I'm okay with it, even if the answer is similar. The other question is more about internal links; this question is more about typesetting URLs in general.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I thought this was a duplicate but I think I was thinking of email addresses. URLs are simple:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
...
\url{http://google.com}
```

Colours can be changed by setting up `hyperref` as desired:

```
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks, linkcolor=red
}
```

If you're not using `hyperref` then load the `url` package:

```
\usepackage{url}
...
\url{http://google.com}
```

but you won't get hyperlinks, of course.

Answer (score 31):

Also,

```
\href{http://google.com}{Google}
```

so that when you press on the word *Google* you get connected to Google's site.

Here is what you should put in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DeepPink4}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=DarkRed}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=DarkBlue}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

This should be placed **as is** at the **bottom** of the list of added packages.

Comment: Why not `\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=DeepPink4,linkcolor=DarkRed, urlcolor=DarkBlue]{hyperref}`? And what is `cleveref` for here?

Comment: maybe also something like `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}` (before `\hypersetup`) to access the named colours