# How to generate this symbol~ in pdf using latex

Tags: urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL with tilde character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10858/url-with-tilde-character)

How to generate this line in pdf using latex.

> http://www.google.com/~find/

How can I create **~find** in latex.

I tried `\~\ find` which creates only

> ~ find

How can I do that....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\usepackage{url}
```

Then `\url{http://www.google.com/~find}`  See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/how-does-one-insert-a-url-correctly) on the TeX StackExchange.

Comment: Trying to make a tilde outside of a url is a mess (see other posts herein) but luckily the `url` package does exactly what we need for urls. In your case this is THE answer. If you really need a tilde, well you found LaTeX's most embarrassing problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
\textasciitilde{}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256457/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex