# Is it possible to have URLs link from a pdf to the webpage?

Tags: links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one insert a URL correctly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/how-does-one-insert-a-url-correctly)

I'm writing up a document, and at one point I cite a file online found at `http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf`

I made a footnote with
`\footnote{http://www.math.uconn.edu/\textasciitilde kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf}`

I had to find an alternative for the `~` since it would not show up in the final document. This works fine when copy+pasting to a web browser, but is it possible to just link to the page from the pdf by clicking on the footnote?

P.S. If there's a better fix to the `~` issue, I'd be glad to see that as well.

Comment: On tildes in general: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312/correctly-typesetting-a-tilde. On tildes in URLs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10858/url-with-tilde-character

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `\href` from the `hyperref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\footnote{\href{http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf}{groups}}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use either the `\url` or `\href` commands from `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \footnote{\url{http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf}}
  \footnote{\href{http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf}{Text printed}}
\end{document}
```

`\url` prints the URL with `\textt` style fonts.
`\href` prints the text that follows the URL. Note that on a printed copy of you article the real URL will not be visible.