# How can I create links within the document to other sectiongs/chapters etc.?

Tags: cross-referencing, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make clickable links and cross-references in pdfs produced by LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-to-make-clickable-links-and-cross-references-in-pdfs-produced-by-latex)

In LaTeX with TeX Live, how can I add links to other parts of the document, e.g. to headings? (real, clickable links, at least in pdf they should be clickable ;) )

Comment: Have a look at: [How to make clickable links and cross-references in pdfs produced by LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-to-make-clickable-links-and-cross-references-in-pdfs-produced-by-latex) and please tell us if that helped.

Comment: Ok, so I close this question as a duplicate.