# How can I make a clickable Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make clickable links and cross-references in pdfs produced by LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-to-make-clickable-links-and-cross-references-in-pdfs-produced-by-latex)

I need links for the Table of Contents, so that I can navigate fast to different sections. I apparently need some package.

I tried the package `url` unsuccessfully.

Comment: It is hilarious that this question was given a duplicate badge when it was asked one year before than the other one. This question was also searchable in Google during the time when the other question was asked. There is also more thorough solution in this question than the other one.

Comment: Very ironic to tag it as [tag:hyperref] ;-)

Answer (score 256, accepted):

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
```

You can change the color of the links as above.

Comment: A few tips: to simply avoid any visual indication of links, use option `hidelinks`. This can also be done like this: `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`.

To set all colors at once, use `allcolors=black`. `colorlinks` seems to work the same as `colorlinks=true`.

Comment: The option `hidelinks` seems to be unnecessary in my XeLaTeX file. Not sure if this is because of XeLaTeX or that the lack of visual indication of links has been made default in hyperref. Somebody might want to investigate.

Comment: This is so awesome! I feel that my work now feels 100 times more professional :D

Comment: Make sure you do not have the “draft” option in the document class. With “draft”, links are not created!

Comment: To use the hyperref package with the cleveref package, you need to place hyperref before cleveref in the preamble.

Answer (score 67):

The package listed is correct.  This is a more detailed account of setup though:

```
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=blue,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}
```

Once this is all setup, you should just be able to include the

```
\tableofcontents
```

sometime after

```
\begin{document}
```

and be all set

Comment: very clear answer

Answer (score 32):

Don't miss out on the

```
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
```

option to only link the page numbers and not the entire table of contents; when links are being coloured the default behaviour can be a bit overwhelming.

Moreover, if you need to use `dviaps+ps2pdf` driver then in the default setting, the hyperlinks of long headers (that occupy more than one line) are scrambled due to a known incompatibility ([README for hyperref](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf), Section 7) and linking the page numbers resolves this issue.

Comment: Not true. It's better when the entire line links.

Comment: As clickable links, it's better to have the entire line. But if you've got links printed in hot pink, then it looks mighty ugly to have an entire page coloured like that.

Comment: A solution to keep the whole line a link (easier to click), while not having the whole TOC colored, is to [change hyperref's linkcolor just for the TOC](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3458#p13513).

Answer (score 31):

The way to go is the [`hyperref`](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html) package.