# Tufte Book Clickable Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, tufte, links, tufte-book

This is my first time posting to this site so I apologize for any and all mistakes on my part.

I am trying to write a document using the `tufte-book` document class. Specifically, I am using the overleaf template given here https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-tufte-style-book-with-vdqi-title-and-contents-page/xqkjxvmrhmmp (this is a link to an overleaf page).

I would like to use this template because of the way it formats the table of contents [TOC]. Yet, I noticed that the TOC is not clickable. I know that the package `hyperref` is by far the recommended choice for making the TOC clickable (as suggested by this post [How can I make a clickable Table of Contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73862/how-can-i-make-a-clickable-table-of-contents) and many others). However, the comments on lines 19-21 of this overleaf template, unfortunately, specifically say that hyperref cannot be used lest the TOC's formatting breaks down. The following line (number 22) looks like this `\documentclass[nohyper,nobib]{tufte-book}`.

So, I would like to ask if there is any (reasonably implementable) way to make a clickable TOC in the `tufte-book` class that does not use the `hyperref` package (while still maintaining this formatting of the TOC)? Or maybe there is a way of getting the TOC to be clickable with `hyperref` while avoiding any issues with the `tufte-book` class?

Thank you for your time and help!

---

**EDIT: Example included**

I realize it was unreasonable to not include a shortened example. What follows is all of the preamble code that I believe is required for the formatting of the title page and TOC. (This has been exactly copy-pasted from the overleaf template, with all unnecessary packages/code removed).

```
%% Unfortunately for the contents to contain
%% the "Parts" lines successfully, hyperref
%% needs to be disabled.
\documentclass[nohyper,nobib]{tufte-book}

% Book metadata
\title{A Tufte-Style Book}
\date{The edition number}
\author[The Tufte-LaTeX Developers (with modifications)]{The Tufte-LaTeX\ Developers (with modifications)}
\publisher{Publisher of This Book}

%%%% Kevin Godny's code for title page and contents from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tufte-latex/ujdzrktC1BQ
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{%
\begingroup%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

{\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont\textit{\@author}\par}

\vspace{1.75in}{\fontsize{36}{54}\selectfont\@title\par}

\vspace{0.5in}{\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\textsf{\smallcaps{\@date}}\par}

\vfill{\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\textit{\@publisher}\par}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\titlecontents{part}%
    [0pt]% distance from left margin
    {\addvspace{0.25\baselineskip}}% above (global formatting of entry)
    {\allcaps{Part~\thecontentslabel}\allcaps}% before w/ label (label = ``Part I'')
    {\allcaps{Part~\thecontentslabel}\allcaps}% before w/o label
    {}% filler and page (leaders and page num)
    [\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}]% after

\titlecontents{chapter}%
    [4em]% distance from left margin
    {}% above (global formatting of entry)
    {\contentslabel{2em}\textit}% before w/ label (label = ``Chapter 1'')
    {\hspace{0em}\textit}% before w/o label
    {\qquad\thecontentspage}% filler and page (leaders and page num)
    [\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}]% after
%%%% End additional code by Kevin Godby
```

A minimal example of the document body would be as follows (my own code).

```
\begin{document}
%%% LAYOUT
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter

%%% PART 1
\part{Example 1}
\chapter{Ex 1 Ch 1}
Testing.
\chapter{Ex 1 Ch 2}
Testing.

%%% PART 2
\part{Example 2}
\chapter{Ex 2 Ch 1}
Testing.
\chapter{Ex 2 Ch 2}
Testing.
\end{document}
```

The TOC would then look like this while also being unclickable.

[image: Example TOC Picture]

Adding the `hyperref` package to the preamble leads to many compiling errors. Changing line 4 in the preamble example above to `\documentclass{tufte-book}` also leads to many errors. (Maybe I should note that only removing the code `nobib` in line 4, so that it becomes `\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-book}`, does not lead to any errors. So it seems `nohyper` is required but not `nobib`.)

---

**EDIT2: Showing errors**

Based off of the comments, this may be a compiler-specific issue. I am using a university service that says "Powered by ShareLatex 2016" and looks almost identical to overleaf. (Please let me know how to provide further specifications if needed).

Upon removing the `nohyper` option from the code above, the table of contents looks like this.

[image: glitched TOC]

So the lines indicating Part I and Part II have changed. I should note that the chapters (Ex 1 Ch1, Ex 2 Ch 2, ... ) become clickable links to the correct pages. However, the lines for Part I and Part II are not clickable.

Some of the errors are

> Undefined control sequence. output.toc, line 1

[image: error example 1]

> Missing control sequence inserted. output.toc, line 1

[image: error example 2]

> Undefined control sequence. output.toc, line 4

[image: error example 3]

> Extra \endgroup. output.toc, line 52

[image: error example 4]

> Package ifplatform Warning: shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

None of these errors seem to occur when using overleaf. Unfortunately, for this project, I have to use the university-provided service.

If there are better ways of showing the errors, please let me know.

Comment: You need hyperref for the links. I can't tell you if can adapt your template, as you didn't provide a small example here and I won't debug a template from an external site.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the suggestion; I apologize for the lack of an example. I have edited the question to include one now.

Comment: @stowo If I puzzle your code fragments into one document, I can remove the `nohyper` option without problem. The toc becomes clickable and it compiles without errors. What errors do you get without the `nohyper` option?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz wow, so I have put the same code into overleaf and it compiles smoothly just as you said. I was originally using a university owned latex service that says it is "powered by ShareLatex 2016" (and it looks almost exactly like overleaf). In that compiler, when removing the ```nohyper``` option, I got 16 errors. Most of them say "undefined control sequence", "missing control sequence inserted", "extra \endgroup" and they all cite of "output.toc" lines 1, 4 or 52. I dont know how to access the "ouput.toc" file. I think it gets automatically deleted by the compiler

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I apologize, if there is a better way to share the errors, please let me know. I am happy to edit the post again and include pictures. Maybe I should also note the last error says "Package ifplatform Warning: shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows."

Comment: I have now edited the post to show the errors which occur. I completely understand if this issue is too dependent on the compiler and cannot be reasonably answered by this site.

Comment: @stowo The problem is probably the outdated latex version from sharelatex 2016.