# Cleveref Links missing

Tags: cross-referencing, links, cleveref

i have a problem with cleveref. I'm using cleveref with the nameinlink-option but there is still no link. 
This is my header:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig,color}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\geometry{
  left=2cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=3cm,
  bindingoffset=5mm
}

\usepackage{dsfont}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.pdftex}{pdf}{.pdftex}{}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{caption}
```

And i'm using:

```
\Cref{cor:simplification}
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `cleveref` doesn't create clickable links, if that's what you mean. Add `\usepackage{hyperref}` before `\usepackage{cleveref}`.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in comments, `cleveref` does not by itself produce hyperlinks, it only handles the formatting of the references. To make cross references (and citations and footnotes) into clickable links, add the `hyperref` package, as mentioned in [How to make clickable links and cross-references in pdfs produced by LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-to-make-clickable-links-and-cross-references-in-pdfs-produced-by-latex)

`hyperref` should, as a rule of thumb, be the last package loaded, as it redefines a lot of stuff, but `cleveref` is an exception to this rule (see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before/)). Hence, in the preamble you should have

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

in that order.

Addendum: No everyone is a fan of the default look of hyperlinks, which is red rectangles around the text. To modify this you could add use the `hidelinks` or `colorlinks` option to the package, as described in the answers to [Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks)