# referencing papers

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

In scientific pdfs one often reads sentences with the corresponding papers in ()-brakets from which the information is taken: e.g. blablabla (Super Mario et al. *2005*). Often the year is blue painted and when you click on it, then you are lead to the reference of the cited paper at the end of the pdf. When clicking on the coloured parts there one is even lead to the location in the internet where the respective paper can be downloaded.
How is this coded?

Comment: `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-to-make-clickable-links-and-cross-references-in-pdfs-produced-by-latex?lq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks?lq=1, your question is a duplicate of the first of these I suppose. Also note that `hyperref` should generally be among the last packages you load, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before

Comment: Note that this is to do with citations and bibliographies rather than cross-referencing, which concerns references to other parts of your document. So you would use `hyperref` together with something to manage your bibliography. `bibtex` and `biblatex` are popular choices.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Lets take this paper as an example http://m.iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/720/2/1691/pdf/0004-637X_720_2_1691.pdf

Comment: If possible give the used package, the used command in the text, and the used command in the reference.

Comment: The properties of that PDF says *Creator: LaTeX with hyperref package*. Add the command I first wrote to the preamble, and any `\cite`, `\ref` or `\url` you add in your text will be a clickable hyperlink.